# LibGDX Android Stringbuilder most efficient Way?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, stringbuilder

Good Day to you all,
i have a little Question, what would be the best way to often add a lot of different Strings to an other String especially in LibGDX?

```
blockString=new StringBuilder(blockString).append(String.valueOf(blockCount.length/2+i)).append("][").append(String.valueOf(f)).append("]").append(String.valueOf(t)).toString();
```

I have to do this method several hundred Times in as little Time as possible. Does anyone have an Idea what would be the most efficient way to do that in LibGdx on Android?

Thanks in advance for the Answers

**EDIT**

whole loop:

```
                for (int i=-300;i<300;i++){
                    //whole world Generation(taking up nearly no time)
                    int f=0;
                    int max=50;
                    while (f<max){
                        if (blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][0][0]==32&&blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][0][1]==0){
                            max=f;
                        }
                        if (!(blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][0]==32&&blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][1]==0)){
                            int t=codeTexture(blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][0],blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][1]);
                            blockString=blockString.concat("["+String.valueOf(blockCount.length/2+i)+"]"+"["+String.valueOf(f)+"]"+String.valueOf(t));

                        }
                        if ((blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][0]==48&&blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][1]==64)||(blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][0]==32&&blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][1]==64)||(blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][0]==0&&blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][1]==64)||(blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][0]==0&&blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][1]==0)||(blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][0]==16&&blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][1]==16)){
                            max=f+10;
                        }
                        f=f+1;
                    }
                 }
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you're not using `+`? The final code would be equivalent.

Comment: Because for some weird reason i think i get a performance with append, i think it's because the stringbuilder class i imported is from Libgdx and not Java itself, but i'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've written will perform exactly the same as the much more straightforward

```
blockString += (blockCount.length / 2 + i) + "][" + t;
```

Edit: to do this in a loop, your code should really look like

```
StringBuilder blockStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i=-300;i<300;i++){
                //whole world Generation(taking up nearly no time)
                int f=0;
                int max=50;
                while (f<max){
                    if (blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][0][0]==32&&blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][0][1]==0){
                        max=f;
                    }
                    if (!(blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][0]==32&&blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][1]==0)){
                        int t=codeTexture(blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][0],blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][1]);
                        blockStringBuilder.append("[").append(blockCount.length/2+i).append("][").append(f).append("]").append(t);

                    }
                    if ((blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][0]==48&&blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][1]==64)||(blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][0]==32&&blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][1]==64)||(blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][0]==0&&blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][1]==64)||(blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][0]==0&&blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][1]==0)||(blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][0]==16&&blockCount[blockCount.length/2+i][f][1]==16)){
                        max=f+10;
                    }
                    f=f+1;
                }
             }
             blockString = blockStringBuilder.toString();
```

Comment: I just don't understand why this operation*26 takes 256milliseconds on a galaxy s3...isn't there any better way? i mean i have to perform this operation around 5600 times which makes around 1 minute waiting just for my terrain Generation and just because of this one line of Code :/

Comment: Are you doing this in a loop, then?

Comment: Yep its a 2D Array that i have to convert in a certain way but,strangely blockString=blockString.concat(...), only needs half the time so i'think i'm gonna go with that for now but Thanks for the advice

Comment: If you're doing this in a loop, you should be doing the whole thing in a StringBuilder, not converting back into a String each time, or the whole thing will take quadratic time.

Comment: the problem is i have to decide for each object of the array individually if i want to put it in my String so i think there is no way around the loop but i'm getting pretty good generating times with the blockString.concat...or at least acceptable since this only has to happen once when the player starts the game for the first time.

Comment: If you show us the whole loop, not just this one statement, we can help you figure that out.  This can definitely be massively faster if you're doing this in a loop.

Comment: Added the improved version.  You should _definitely_ be doing something like this, where you're appending into a `StringBuilder`, not repeatedly converting to and from a String.